# Parallel python extract by mask ArcGIS

Tags: python, parallel-processing, arcgis

I found the following code in a [previous](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94092/script-to-extract-by-mask-a-list-of-raster-files) answer. I tried it for about 3000 rasters, it works but very slow. How to excute the code in parallel to fasten the process?

thanks,
moh

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = "C:/rasters/threshold"
outws = "C:/SIG/MelasCA_30runs_avg/threshold/mesoamerica"
mask = "C:/GIS/mesoamerica.shp"

rasterlist = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "Raster")
for i in rasterlist:
    outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(i, mask)
    outname = os.path.join(outws, str(i)) # Create the full out path
    outExtractByMask.save(outname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use threads. Depending on the number of cores you have, execute 4/8/16 simultanously.
Hints for using threads:
https://pymotw.com/2/threading/

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem is, I have really no background in python at all. I usally use gdal, but the results is not satisfactory. Of course I was happy to find an already working code. Would appreciate any help to adjust the code to work in parallel. But I promise, will start learning python :))